# How to hide turn instructions in Mapbox gl directions?

Tags: ionic4, mapbox-gl-js

I am using Mapbox gl in Ionic - v4, As showing in Mapbox docs i have added [Display driving directions](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-directions/). With direction control it showing turn instructions and i want hide turn instruction.

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = environment.mapbox.accessToken;
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
center: [-79.4512, 43.6568],
zoom: 13
});

map.addControl(new MapboxDirections({
accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
}), 'top-left');
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing issues while implementing the MapboxDirections control. Can you tell me how did you implemented it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [reference](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/API.md) says:

> options.controls.instructions Boolean Hide or display the instructions control. (optional, default true)

So the code like this

```
map.addControl(new MapboxDirections({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
    controls: {instructions: false}
}), 'top-left');
```

should work.